# Can´t connect to my Amazon EC2 instance. It pings but connection times out

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I did setup my 1st EC2 instance on AWS on a free tier using Ubuntu as the OS. I followed all the steps and my instance is up.

I´ve build the following security rules:

```
Ports   Protocol    Source  Personal_SG_NVirginia
80      tcp         0.0.0.0/0   ✔
22      tcp         0.0.0.0/0   ✔
3306    tcp         0.0.0.0/0   ✔
443     tcp         0.0.0.0/0   ✔
-1      icmp        0.0.0.0/0   ✔
```

I can ping my instance, but cannot connect to it either using PuTTY, ssh on my linux and even on miniterm console.

```
$ ssh -vv -i "xxxx.pem" ubuntu@52.91.95.205
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 52.91.95.205 [52.91.95.205] port 22
debug1: connect to address 52.91.95.205 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 52.91.95.205 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Tha same happens if I use DNS name.

Miniterm console error:

```
Connection to 52.91.95.205: Connection timed out: no further information
```

I have already restarted the instance and recreated it, but no success at all.

Help appreciatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Verify the IP address is valid**

`$ ssh -vv -i "xxxx.pem" ubuntu@54.210.1133.50`

Is this hand-written or did you copy and paste? The IP address is an invalid IP address ("1133" is >255), and doesn't match your debug output. Make sure you're connecting to the correct public IP address of the instance.

**Verify you are using the correct user**

Are you sure the initial user is "ubuntu"? Some EC2 Linux instances use "ec2-user" for the initial setup.

Try: `ssh -vv -i "xxxx.pem" ec2-user@123.123.123.123`

**Verify default SSH port is not blocked (correct solution)**

Per discussion below, it turns out that port 22 was blocked by the user's ISP. Switching to a non-standard port (2022) resolved the issue.

Comment: O copied it wrong... It´s a typo.. .Yes, I´m connecting to the right IP address...  About the "ubuntu/' user is right...I´m using ubuntu. I created a sencond instance with amazon linux "ec2-user" and is not working the same way... On miniterm it does not work also, and the connection is made directly from AWS console button... No typos there... Seens something wrong with networking...

Comment: Guess that's my CentOS preference leaking through. Have you checked your VPC security groups and ACLs? Did you make any changes there that could be affecting your connection?

Comment: I´m using the default accound parameters - so I haven´t touched VPC´s or ACL´s... The only thing I´ve created is a new security rule as posted above...

Comment: Did you set the correct permissions on your .pem file? ``ssh_connect: needpriv 0`` might be saying to ``chmod 600`` your .pem file.

Comment: Yes. Interesting, I moved my notebook to another place with a different connection and it went trhough... Sees something related to my ISP.... What can be causing that ?

Comment: Ah, some ISPs block port 22. Change to a non-default port (like 2222) in ``sshd_config`` when you're able to get in, and use the ``ssh ... -p 2222`` argument.

Comment: It was indeed a ISP problem. Port 2022 is working fine now. Thanks for helping.